# Fetch data to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the API request link - http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/countries/ASI?apikey=r0wWEqEDfOM8KwWLIIw8ADXHu2JhgyeB

I need to update the data in the google sheet with ID in one column and Country Name in another column in Google Sheets

The JSON output is for the 1st two ID is as follows

```
[
    {
        "ID": "AF",
        "LocalizedName": "Afghanistan",
        "EnglishName": "Afghanistan"
    },
    {
        "ID": "AM",
        "LocalizedName": "Armenia",
        "EnglishName": "Armenia"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Google Sheets rows are arrays, where each member represents a column value.
Your code should look something like this:

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('yourSpreadsheetId').getSheetByName('yourSheetName');
const data = [
    {
        "ID": "AF",
        "LocalizedName": "Afghanistan",
        "EnglishName": "Afghanistan"
    },
    {
        "ID": "AM",
        "LocalizedName": "Armenia",
        "EnglishName": "Armenia"
    },
]; // replace with your data fetch logic

// collect your row data into array of arrays
const rows = [];
for (const location of data) {
  rows.push([location.ID, location.LocalizedName]);
}

// get range beginning at the first row and first column,
// with number of rows equels to amount of rows, and 2 as a number of cols
// and fill it with your data
sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, 2).setValues(rows);
```

See docs for [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid), [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet), [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet), [Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns), [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the `ARRAYFORMULA`. Try this in any cell in your blank Google sheet:

`=arrayformula(split(trim(flatten(split(join(" ",regexreplace(transpose(IMPORTDATA("http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/countries/ASI?apikey=r0wWEqEDfOM8KwWLIIw8ADXHu2JhgyeB")),"(\{.*ID.*\:)|(LocalizedName.*)|(EnglishName)|([""\[\]])","")),"}"))),":"))`

`IMPORTDATA` gets your content from http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/countries/ASI?apikey=r0wWEqEDfOM8KwWLIIw8ADXHu2JhgyeB

`TRANSPOSE` transposes it.

`REGEXREPLACE` removes a few sets of characters.

`JOIN` merges onto one row.

`SPLIT` splits into columns by `}`.

`FLATTEN` flattens the result into a column.

`TRIM` gets rid of leading/trailing spaces.

`SPLIT` splits into columns by `:`.

`ARRAYFORMULA` works down the sheet.